# pause a specific action on sprite

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I've a player of Sprite * type in cocos2dx V3, I want it to run different animation on different time interval, I could not find method to pause and then resume a specific animation(Action). Although I can Pause and Resume all actions of Sprite Simultaneously using _player->pauseSchedulerAndActions().I'm using "`CCRepeatForever`" actions on sprite, so, I must have to pause one to resume other.Please help to Pause an action by tag or by any other method.
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oops**

I made the assumption that this was Objective-C but @Droppy has informed me that it is not.

I didn't realise `cocos2d-x` was different. However, because this is a fairly high level framework the concept behind what I've done in the answer will still work. I'll keep the answer here for now.

**The answer**

It's been a while since I've done any Cocos2D stuff but I can give you the idea.

Instead of creating an action and repeating it forever you should have a method something like this...

```
- (void)twirlAround
{
    // only create and perform the actions if variable set to YES
    if (self.twirling) {
        // this will do your action once.
        CCAction *twirlAction = // create your twirl action (or whatever it is)

        // this will run this function again
        CCAction *repeatAction = [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
            [self twirlAround];
        }];

        // put the action and method call in sequence.
        CCActionSequence *sequence = [CCActionSequence actions:@[twirlAction, repeatAction]];

        [self runAction:sequence];
    }
}
```

This will run repeatedly as long as the `twirling` property is set to `YES`.

So, somewhere else in your code (probably where you are currently adding your repeating action) you can do this...

```
self.twirling = YES;
[self twirlAround];
```

This will start the repeated twirling.

To stop it you can then do...

```
self.twirling = NO;
```

This will stop the twirling.

**Alternative method**

```
- (void)twirlAround
{
    // this will do your action once.
    CCAction *twirlAction = // create your twirl action (or whatever it is)

    // this will run this function again
    CCAction *repeatAction = [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
        if (self.twirling) {
            [self twirlAround];
        }
    }];

    // put the action and method call in sequence.
    CCActionSequence *sequence = [CCActionSequence actions:@[twirlAction, repeatAction]];

    [self runAction:sequence];
}
```

Comment: @Droppy ah, I didn't know that. With there not being any code and it being tagged iOS I made an assumption. The concept is still exactly the same though.

Comment: Agreed; there is still some value to your answer.

Comment: guessing c++ version of these functions are not difficult. in my opinion, it is good idea

Comment: Thanks @Fogmeister, But according to this, twirlAround function must have to check again and again for "YES" or "NO" value and it must be in some scheduler or in loop. But In my case, It's being called just once. And when I've to Run another action, I need to pause this one, not to call this function again.

Comment: @BilalHassan well, you could do it the other way around and put the check for YES/NO in the action block... Edited to show. But you will always have to check the value of twirling.

Comment: @BilalHassan edit, oh I just understood your comment. No you are incorrect. The twirl around method calls itself recursively (sort of). However, the recursion only occurs if the value of `twirling` is YES. So to start it repeating you set `twirling` to YES and then call the `twirlAround` method. I explained this in the second half of my answer.

Comment: @BilalHassan the whole point of this set up is that if `twirling` is set to YES then when you run `twirlAround` it will start looping and it will look like a repeating action. But as soon as you set `twirling` to NO it will stop the loop. There is no scheduler required.

Answer (score 1):

based on Fogmeister advice, this is cocos2d-x version of that

```
void MySprite::jumpForever(){
   if (!twirling) return;
   auto jump = JumpBy::create(0.5, Vec2(0, 0), 100, 1);
   auto endCallback = CallFuncN::create(CC_CALLBACK_1(MySprite::jumpForever,this));
   auto seq = Sequence::create(jump, endCallback, nullptr);
   runAction(seq);
}
```

Comment: OK, C++ implementation of the same thing :D I could never have written this off the top of my head. Thanks :D

Comment: @Fogmeister c++ has also similar functions :) writing easy after a workable solution